# Docker in Google App Engine Flexible health check has wrong URL

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

My service uses a url like this:

`<google_url>/v1/lookup_stuff`

`<google_url>/v1/` is the base url for everything in the service, so when the health check pings `<google_url>` it gets a 404. I need to update to ping `<google_url>/v1/`

(Possibly useful information, the service is in Docker, and is accessible when I manually go to the right URL)

How do I point gcloud's health service at the correct URL for my service?

Ok for clarity:

- Google url: `service-something.appspot.com`
- All urls for service are under:  `service-something.appspot.com/v1`

I need to point health checker to:

- `service-something.appspot.com/v1/_ah/health`

instead of

- `service-something.appspot.com/_ah/health`

Comment: It might help people understand your question if you clearly state what your question is. What are you asking?

Comment: I want the (gcloud autogenerated) health service to get a 200 OK...not a 404 not found

Comment: Ok. I suggest adding that to the end of your question, in the form of a question. ("How do I... ?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The flexible environment now supports the [Updated health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks), consisting of separately configurable [liveness checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#liveness_path) and/or [readiness checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#readiness_path), both with a configurable `path` capability.

Note that these updated health checks are not compatible and cannot coexit with the legacy health checks:

> You must enable updated health checks for each project individually.
>   By default, legacy health checks are enabled. You cannot use both
>   types of health checks in the same project.

**Original answer, applicable only to the legacy health checks:**

The path is not currently configurable. From [Health checking](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-instances-are-managed#health_checking):

> You do not have to do anything special to implement health checking.
>   If your app does not handle health checks, a HTTP `404` response is
>   interpretated as a successful reply.
>
> You can write your own custom health-checking code. It should reply to
>   `/_ah/health` requests with a HTTP status code `200`. The response
>   must include a message body, however, the value of the body is ignored
>   (it can be empty).

So you can leave it like that - your app being always considered healthy. Or you can teach your app to correctly answer to the health check requests at `/_ah/health`.

Comment: I really wish Google would 1. make this more obvious (that their health checker has absolutely no way to change where it points) and 2. add features like this.

Comment: Check if this fits your suggestion and maybe file a feature request if not: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900811

Comment: Yup, that exactly fits what I want. Thanks for the link.  Hopefully that moves up their backlog sometime this year  :/

Comment: Ok, so I have another closely related question.  I changed the app setup to host at    `<service>.appspot.com/_ah/health`  and can get a 200 from that page, but the logs still show a 404.  Is  _ah/health actually at a different location?  Also why doesn't   `login: admin` secure /_ah/health from the outside world?

Comment: Ask it as a separate question and add more info to it. I don't think I really understand the problem you describe - if you get a 404 it's not properly configured, I'd say.

Comment: When I directly access the URL from my web browser, I get a 200.  When google health checker pings what *should* be the same url, it gets a 404. On top of that `login: admin` has no effect on that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Really cryptic-ly exposed question, anyway:

- <strike>if `<google_url>` is a tag that you designed then split it in two: `<google_base_url>/v1/` and `<google_path_url>lookup_stuff` then you can ping `<google_base_url>/v1/` and when you need the original `<google_url> = <google_base_url> + <google_path_url>`</strike>
- if `<google_url>` is given to you by some framework, etc, then you need to interpret it, to get the initial part that you need. Maybe you can use a regex pattern, check out [this so search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex%20to%20extract%20url)
- a third option is to put a rewrite rule in your web service that will redirect all the pings to the url you need, again [check out this so search for apache](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rewrite%20rule%20apache), and or expand your question explaining what web server you use, what you intend doing, etc etc

Last, check out this nice example on [kubernetes-health-check](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) about how configure the liveness probe, there is a path parameter that should be useful

Comment: I'm asking how to redirect what gcloud's built in health checker is pinging.  It defaults to the autogenerated URL google provides for your service. I need to redirect it to <google_url>/v1/health_check  or something similar.

Comment: last option is the only one that I see feasible, given the updates to your question, is this on apache? can you write an .htaccess file with a rewrite rule?

Comment: Server is a Swagger generated Python server (using connexion/flask).