# Setting up Handlers for Docker service in Gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, handler, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

I am deploying a docker service to Gcloud. The service is internal and needs external public access disabled. The only way I see to do this is using handlers for the service, but there is no way I see to use handlers with a Docker service.

From the example  google app engine:

```
handlers:
    - url: /_ah/push-handlers/.*
      login: admin
      script: main.app
```

This doesn't appear to work for docker since none of the scripts are directly accessible, and the URL is set inside the docker container.

How do I setup a handler (or at least disable external access to the service) for a docker container?

Comment: Ignore the `script:` value, the flex env is not using it. At least in the java docs we see: `script: this field is required, but ignored`. But is the `login: admin` portion of the config effective? It seems to be recommended, for example see `Security Constraints` in https://tech.small-improvements.com/2016/09/12/running-our-app-engine-application-in-the-flexible-environment-java-8/. See also  the inconsistencies mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363766/cron-job-in-google-app-engine-not-working/45363938#45363938

Comment: Thanks.  Would you also possibly know how to change where the health checker is pointed in the flex environment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470889/docker-in-google-cloud-health-check-has-wrong-url